# How to use shell variables after doing sudo su

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, environment-variables

I am writing a script to fix a missing 'F' letter in a mail log file. The mail log file is continuously updating. I am getting a file name, after that I am doing 'sudo su' to get superuser access. Inside sudo, I am fixing a that missing 'F'. However, I am unable to use that file name inside sudo block. Please can anyone help me how I can export these shell variables inside sudo? I tried using export but its not working. The code block I have created is as follows-

```
 #Script to solve F issue
#----------------------------------------
#By Kapil Shirsath
#----------------------------------------

cd /var/spool/mail        #mail files reside in mail folder
echo "Entered in mail folder"

filename=`ls -lrt  99999*| sort -k 5 -rn | head -1 | tr -s " " "," | cut -d "," -f "8"`    # this will list the file with maximum size`

echo "File with maximum size is  $filename"
echo "----------------------------------------------------"
echo "Is it the file expected?(y/n)"
read choice
if test $choice == "n"
then
    echo "Exiting...."
    exit;
fi;

c=1
while [ $c -le 5 ]
do
    ls -lrt $filename
    echo $filename
    sleep 3
    c=`expr $c + 1`
done
echo "---------------------------------------------------"

sudo su<<'HERE'   #this will give you super user permissions
echo "Got root access"
echo "First line of the file is as below :"
head -1 $filename
echo "---------------------------------------"
firstline=`head -1 $filename`
echo "Repeat : $firstline"
echo $firstline | grep ^"rom" >/dev/null
if test $? -eq 0
then
ex -s $filename <<'EOF'
1s/^/F/
:wq
EOF
echo "F issue fixed!"
HERE


c=1
while [ $c -le 5 ]
do
    ls -lrt $filename
    sleep 3
    c=`expr $c + 1`
done
echo "---------------------------------------------------"  
else
    echo "Not finding the missing 'F' ! !! Kindly check with your system "
    exit;
fi;
```

Answer (score 2):

You quoted the heredoc delimiter:

> ```
> sudo su<<'HERE'
> ```

Variables in a heredoc are not expanded if the delimiter is quoted. [From the docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents):

> If any characters in *word* are quoted, the *delimiter* is the result of
>   quote removal on *word*, and the lines in the here-document are not
>   expanded. If *word* is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are
>   subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic
>   expansion, the character sequence `\newline` is ignored, and ‘`\`’ must be
>   used to quote the characters ‘`\`’, ‘`$`’, and ‘`` ` ``’.

Just use:

```
sudo su <<HERE
```

Example:

```
$ a=1; cat <<HERE
> $a
> HERE
1
$ a=1; cat <<'HERE'
> $a
> HERE    
$a
```